# Name tables which are related the same number but different letters or numbers A,B,C or 1,2,3,4... E.g. 1A, 1B, 1C

Tags: tables

In my thesis, I have several instances where I have too many variables to include in one Table. Instead of letting the tables continue on the following page, I have split the tables into two or more tables according to some criteria specific to each Table. I wish to number the tables: Table 1A, Table 1B, Table 1C (for a table that is split into three tables).
So is there a way of "linking" separate tables, such that the caption contains a common number (1), but separate letters (A, B, C).
Perhaps the closest alternative that comes to my mind, it the use of "subequations", when I want to link selected equations, which allow me to name subequations 2a, 2b, 2c, etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

With the help of `\subfloat` and `\ContinuedFloat` from the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}[bp]
\centering
  \subfloat[first sub table caption]{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      first column & second column \\
    \end{tabular}
  }
  
  \subfloat[second subtable caption]{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      first column & second column \\
    \end{tabular}
  }
\caption{table cpation}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\ContinuedFloat
  \subfloat[third subtable caption]{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      first column & second column \\
    \end{tabular}
  }
  
  \subfloat[fourth subtable caption]{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      first column & second column \\
    \end{tabular}
  }
\caption{table caption}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How might the code be adapted to meet the OP's objective of numbering the subtables as `1A`, `1B`, etc rather than as `a`, `b`, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that employs the `subcaption` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,margin=5mm]{geometry} % just for this example

\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subtable' env. and '\ContinuedFloat' macro

\captionsetup[subtable]{skip=0.333\baselineskip,font=normalsize}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\thetable\Alph{subtable}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subtable}{} % no prefix in cross-references
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{A table with three sub-tables}
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{The first subtable} \label{tab:1a}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f \\
g & h & i & j & k & l \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat % <-- very important
%\caption{A table with three sub-tables, continued} % optional
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{The second subtable} \label{tab:1b}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f \\
g & h & i & j & k & l \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat % <-- very important
%\caption{A table with three sub-tables, continued} % optional
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{The third subtable} \label{tab:1c}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f \\
g & h & i & j & k & l \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

Cross-references to sub-tables \ref{tab:1a} and \ref{tab:1c}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mico. This is a very nice suggestion. One problem is, however, that all of my 'sub-tables' are named "1A" when I try to incorporate your suggestion into my framework. I obtain the error, "missing number, treated as zero", for the \ContinuedFloat, and I think this may be what causes the problem. Do you have any suggestions on what I may have done wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @CecilieS.K - Since the answer I posted does *not* produce the number  "1A" over and over again, there must be something about your code that's materially different from mine. Please provide more information about your code, so as to remove any need to guess what it is you're doing.